# How long should a poster expect to have before their post is deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted on `Meta` three days ago suggesting a new Exchange topic.  My post was placed on hold within 5 minutes and I was told to check out `Area51`.  I asked the person who placed the hold whether the post could be migrated to `Area51` or if I should move it myself.  I was told posts could not be migrated to `Area51` and that `Area51` deals with projects rather than questions and answers per se.

I had never been to `Area51`.  So I went to that site, registered and briefly looked for projects related to the one I was proposing.

Within 10 minutes of posting my original suggestion on `Meta` I tried to return to the post to copy and save it on my hard-drive.  I had spent almost an hour writing the post and did not want to have to create a modified version of it from scratch on `Area51`.  However, the post was gone.

In retrospect I should have gone to `Area51` to begin with, and would have if I knew it existed and what its purpose is.  I am just a little disappointed that I lost almost an hour of work in 10 minutes.  I had no idea a post might be deleted so quickly or I would have saved the post to my hard-drive before even posting it on `Meta` or certainly before taking the time to register at `Area51`.  I will know to do that in the future.

Deleting a post within approximately 5 minutes after the poster offers to move that post seems extreme to me, especially when the poster is advised to check out a different site and spends the ~five minutes doing just that.  Why delete a post that is obviously not spam so quickly after the poster has expressed a willingness to move the post to a different site?  If five minutes is not extreme, how long should a poster expect to have before their post is deleted?  Is it fair to say a poster should always be prepared for their post to be deleted virtually instantaneously?

Comment: Does this do you any good…? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/476

Comment: The question is still in your profile, and not even deleted yet.

Comment: @deceze It says `No deleted recent questions`.

Comment: Uhm, yes, because *the post isn't actually deleted!*

Comment: Your question wasn't deleted, it was put on hold: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343013/should-there-be-a-sociology-stack-exchange

Comment: @nhahtdh I cannot find it. Can you provide a link to the question?

Comment: @MarkMiller: Click on your name, check the list of Newest Questions/Posts/Answer under Top tags and switch it to Questions (if it's not already Newest Questions).

Comment: @nhahtdh  Thank you.  I found it.  I do not understand why it is not listed on my user page where the other forums are listed.  But at least I was able to copy the post now.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Now that I have been able to copy and save that post I will go ahead and delete it (if able).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you ask an off-topic or non-constructive question, you should expect to have *zero minutes* before your question is deleted. In practice, it may be longer, but you should not have expectations of anything else.

In other less-egregious cases, it is indeed customary to wait a few days before deleting the question. But because these deletions are handled by the community, and Meta is actively moderated, questions that are perceived to be useless may be deleted more quickly.

Regardless, you can always find *recently* deleted questions in your user profile: go [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=questions) (which shows your non-deleted questions), and click the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you.  Perhaps there are multiple Meta forums and only one was listed on my customary user page?

Comment: Your Meta profile and your Stack Overflow (main) profile are different. You might have been looking at the latter?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I was looking at the Meta forum listed on my Stack Overflow page.